# How do I add a "Add more" button?

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I want to  show a *Add more* button that adds an extra text field and the corresponding *Remove* button.

I followed [`ajax_example_add_more()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_graceful_degradation.inc/function/ajax_example_add_more/7.x-1.x) to achieve this in Drupal 7. For Drupal 8, I tried with the following code.

```
class XmlfeedsSettingsForm extends FormBase {
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'formid';
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   // Because we have many fields with the same values, we have to set
  // #tree to be able to access them.
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
  $form['names_fieldset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('People coming to the picnic'),
    // Set up the wrapper so that AJAX will be able to replace the fieldset.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  // Build the fieldset with the proper number of names. We'll use
  // $form_state['num_names'] to determine the number of textfields to build.
  $form_state->getValue['num_names_parent'] = '';
  if (empty($form_state->getValue['num_names_parent'])) {
    $form_state->getValue['num_names_parent'] = 1;
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state->getValue['num_names_parent']; $i++) {
    $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Name'),
    );
  }
  $form['names_fieldset']['add_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add one more'),
    '#submit' => array('::ajax_example_add_more_add_one'),
    // See the examples in ajax_example.module for more details on the
    // properties of #ajax.
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '::ajax_example_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
    ),
  );
  if ($form_state->getValue['num_names_parent'] > 1) {
    $form['names_fieldset']['remove_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Remove one'),
      '#submit' => array('::ajax_example_add_more_remove_one'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '::ajax_example_add_more_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ),
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  // This simply allows us to demonstrate no-javascript use without
  // actually turning off javascript in the browser. Removing the #ajax
  // element turns off AJAX behaviors on that element and as a result
  // ajax.js doesn't get loaded.
  // For demonstration only! You don't need this.
 // if ($no_js_use) {
    // Remove the #ajax from the above, so ajax.js won't be loaded.
//    if (!empty($form['names_fieldset']['remove_name']['#ajax'])) {
//      unset($form['names_fieldset']['remove_name']['#ajax']);
//    }
//    unset($form['names_fieldset']['add_name']['#ajax']);
 // }

  return $form;
  }
  public function ajax_example_add_more_add_one(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      print_R($form_state);die;
  //$form_state->getValue['num_names_parent']++;
  //$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);


}
public function ajax_example_add_more_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['names_fieldset'];

}
public function ajax_example_add_more_remove_one(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($form_state->getValue['num_names_parent'] > 1) {
    $form_state->getValue['num_names_parent']--;
  }
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

`print_r($form_state)` in `buildForm()` outputs the following.

```
[getValue] => Array
        (
            [num_names_parent] => 1
        )
```

In `ajax_example_add_more_add_one()`, the *num_names_parent* index is missing.

How can I correctly add the *Add more* button?

Comment: Ok, which form you want this 'add_more' behavior? If you talking about Fields, just change storage setting to anything higher than 1.

Comment: I have edit in the questions, It is basically any custom form, so field storage is not required here I think. Any possible way to achieve it?

Comment: Looking at the core, I found how Drupal implements this behavior, take a look in `WidgetBase.php`. If you need more help just ask. (there is no remove button, empty fields will be ignored).

Comment: @see https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_api_example%21src%21Form%21AjaxAddMore.php/class/AjaxAddMore/8.x-1.x

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works !! Try this

```php
<?php
  
namespace Drupal\fapi_example\Form;
   
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
  
class AjaxAddMore extends FormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['description'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<div>'. $this->t('This example shows an add-more and a remove-last button.').'</div>',
    );

    $i = 0;
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
    if (empty($name_field)) {
      $name_field = $form_state->set('num_names', 1);
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $name_field; $i++) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      ];
    }
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => array('::addOne'),
      '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
      'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
    if ($name_field > 1) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['remove_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Remove one'),
      '#submit' => array('::removeCallback'),
       '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ]
      ];
    }
    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
  
    return $form;
  }
  
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'fapi_example_ajax_addmore';
  }

  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $add_button = $name_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_names', $add_button);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
  }

  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    if ($name_field > 1) {
      $remove_button = $name_field - 1;
      $form_state->set('num_names', $remove_button);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
  
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValue(array('names_fieldset', 'name'));
  
    $output = t('These people are coming to the picnic: @names', array(
      '@names' => implode(', ', $values),
      )
    );
    drupal_set_message($output);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the usage of  `$form_state->setCached(FALSE);` this line? What if I don't write this line? Also, we generally write form like `$form['foo'] = array();`  but you didn't use this format, instead you simply used `$form['foo'] = [];` What's teh difference b/w these two formats?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-difference-between-array-and  and if you have any other question please post it as a question rather than discussing it in this comment thread .

Answer (score 5):

If reporting error is turned on then the code Shreya Shetty returns error - might be related to changes in Drupal 8 ... but it is related to objects not being able to be used as ints... the amended version would be:

```
namespace Drupal\dynamic_forms\Form;


 use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
 use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

  class test3 extends FormBase {

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['description'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<div>'. t('This example shows an add-more and a remove-last button.').'</div>',
    );
    $i = 0;
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];
    if (empty($name_field)) {
        $name_field = $form_state->set('num_names', 1);
    }

    if ($form_state->get('num_names')>0) {
        $value = $form_state->get('num_names');
    }
    else {
        $value=1;
    }
        for ($i = 0; $i < $value; $i++) {
            $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = [
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Name'),
            ];
        }

    $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Add one more'),
        '#submit' => array('::addOne'),
        '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
            'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
    ];
    //        if ($name_field > 1) {
    if ($value > 1) {
        $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['remove_name'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Remove one'),
            '#submit' => array('::removeCallback'),
            '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
                'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
            ]
        ];
    }
    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
}

public function getFormId() {
    return 'fapi_example_ajax_addmore';
}

public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $add_button = $name_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_names', $add_button);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}

public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
}

public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    if ($name_field > 1) {
        $remove_button = $name_field - 1;
        $form_state->set('num_names', $remove_button);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValue(array('names_fieldset', 'name'));

    $output = t('These people are coming to the picnic: @names', array(
            '@names' => implode(', ', $values),
        )
    );
    drupal_set_message($output);
}

}
```

Thought the amended version might help someone, especially newcomers... don't forget to say thanks to Shreya for original solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (use the get method instead of relying on the return value of the set method for $form_state):

```
if (empty($name_field)) {
  $form_state->set('num_names', 1);
}
$name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
for ($i = 0; $i < $name_field; $i++) {
  $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8:

```
namespace Drupal\form_api_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements the ajax demo form controller.
 *
 * This example demonstrates using ajax callbacks to add people's names to a
 * list of picnic attendees.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase
 */
class AjaxAddMore {

  /**
   * Form with 'add more' and 'remove' buttons.
   *
   * This example shows a button to "add more" - add another textfield, and
   * the corresponding "remove" button.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('This example shows an add-more and a remove-last button.'),
    ];

    // Gather the number of names in the form already.
    $num_names = $form_state->get('num_names');
    // We have to ensure that there is at least one name field.
    if ($num_names === NULL) {
      $name_field = $form_state->set('num_names', 1);
      $num_names = 1;
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_names; $i++) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['name'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name'),
      ];
    }

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];
    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOne'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
    ];
    // If there is more than one name, add the remove button.
    if ($num_names > 1) {
      $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['remove_name'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Remove one'),
        '#submit' => ['::removeCallback'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }
    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_api_example_ajax_addmore';
  }

  /**
   * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
   *
   * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
   */
  public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    $add_button = $name_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_names', $add_button);
    // Since our buildForm() method relies on the value of 'num_names' to
    // generate 'name' form elements, we have to tell the form to rebuild. If we
    // don't do this, the form builder will not call buildForm().
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "remove one" button.
   *
   * Decrements the max counter and causes a form rebuild.
   */
  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $name_field = $form_state->get('num_names');
    if ($name_field > 1) {
      $remove_button = $name_field - 1;
      $form_state->set('num_names', $remove_button);
    }
    // Since our buildForm() method relies on the value of 'num_names' to
    // generate 'name' form elements, we have to tell the form to rebuild. If we
    // don't do this, the form builder will not call buildForm().
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Final submit handler.
   *
   * Reports what values were finally set.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValue(['names_fieldset', 'name']);

    $output = $this->t('These people are coming to the picnic: @names', [
      '@names' => implode(', ', $values),
    ]
    );
    $this->messenger()->addMessage($output);
  }
}
```

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_api_example%21src%21Form%21AjaxAddMore.php/class/AjaxAddMore/8.x-1.x

Answer (score 0):

Tri this add more field with remove button in custom form, I have updated. and work for me.

```
  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Build your form here.
    // Add a wrapper for dynamic fields.
    $form['field_wrapper'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'field-wrapper'],
      '#tree' => TRUE, // Separate values for each field.
    ];

    // Add an "Add Field" button.
    $form['add_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Add Field'),
      '#submit' => ['::addField'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addFieldsAjaxCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'field-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    // Check if there are fields in the form_state and add them.
    $fields = $form_state->get('num_fields') ?: 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++) {
      $form['field_wrapper'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['field-container']],
      ];
      $form['field_wrapper'][$i]['field'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field @index', ['@index' => $i + 1]),
        '#default_value' => $form_state->getValue(['field_wrapper', $i, 'field']),
      ];

      // Add a "Remove" button for each field.
      $form['field_wrapper'][$i]['remove_field'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Remove Field'),
        '#submit' => ['::removeField'],
        '#name' => 'remove_field_' . $i,
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addFieldsAjaxCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'field-wrapper',
        ],
        '#attributes' => ['class' => ['remove-field-button']],
        '#field_index' => $i, // Pass field index to submit handler.
        '#limit_validation_errors' => [
          ['field_wrapper', $i, 'field'],
        ],
      ];

      // Use #prefix and #suffix to hide or show the field based on removal.
      if ($form_state->get(['field_wrapper', $i, 'field_removed'])) {
        $form['field_wrapper'][$i]['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
    }

    return $form;
  }

  public function addField(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $fields = $form_state->get('num_fields') ?: 1;
    $form_state->set('num_fields', $fields + 1);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function removeField(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    $field_index = $triggering_element['#field_index'];

    // Debugging: Check if removeField is called and gets the correct field index.
    \Drupal::logger('my_custom_module')->debug('Remove field called for index: ' . $field_index);

    // Mark the field as removed in the form state.
    $form_state->set(['field_wrapper', $field_index, 'field_removed'], TRUE);

    // Rebuild the form.
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  public function addFieldsAjaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['field_wrapper'];
  }
```